# Can't pop current screen in SwiftUI using NavigationView and NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

So I have a problem regarding **NavigationView** and **NavigationLinks** in **SwiftUI** while trying to pop the current screen, which is not working in this case.

I have 3 Screens A -> B -> C

Each screen has a button for popping itself.

The pop from B -> A works, but when you navigate from A -> B -> C, the pop from C -> B it's not working.

Do you know what would be the problem? I will attach the code below and a video.
The app should support **iOS 14**.

[image]

```
struct ScreenA: View {
    @State private var showB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Go to B") {
                    showB = true
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ScreenB(didTapGoBack: {
                    showB = false
                }), isActive: $showB) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ScreenB: View {
    var didTapGoBack: () -> Void
    @State var showC = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go to C") {
                showC = true
            }
        
            Button("Back to Screen A") {
                didTapGoBack()
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ScreenC(didTapGoBack: {
                showC = false
            }), isActive: $showC) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ScreenC: View {
    var didTapGoBack: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen C")
            Button("Back to Screen B") {
                didTapGoBack()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@main
struct TestNavApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ScreenA()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a solution for this would be adding `.isDetailLink(false)` on the first `NavigationLink`, maybe the `NavigationView` by default works a Split navigation like master-detail, so maybe thats why the first pop was working, but by adding this you are telling the NavigationView to work as a stack.

Now the navigation works as expected A -> B -> C:

```
struct ScreenA: View {
    @State private var showB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Go to B") {
                    showB = true
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ScreenB(didTapGoBack: {
                    showB = false
                }), isActive: $showB) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way to do that and it has the advantage to work :)

you can use the @environment(.dismiss) property and call it to dismiss your current view. It makes your code simpler as well. Here is the result :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScreenA: View {
    @State private var showB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ScreenB(), isActive: $showB) {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var showC = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ScreenC(), isActive: $showC) {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
            
            Button("Back to Screen A") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenC: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen C")
            Button("Back to Screen B") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that NavigationLink(destination:isActive:) is deprecated.

Here is the version with the updated code :

```
struct ScreenA: View {
    @State private var showB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Go to B") {
                    showB = true
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showB ){
                ScreenB()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var showC = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Go to C"){
                showC = true
            }
            
            Button("Back to Screen A") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showC ){
            ScreenC()
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenC: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen C")
            Button("Back to Screen B") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit] for iOS 14 support we need to use `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` as you pointed out in your comment

Here is the iOS 14 version of the code :

```
struct ScreenA: View {
    @State private var showB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ScreenB(), isActive: $showB) {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var showC = false
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ScreenC(), isActive: $showC) {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
            
            Button("Back to Screen A") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScreenC: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen C")
            Button("Back to Screen B") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it's deprecated but the app needs to support iOS 14 :(. I knew that Environment approach works, but I would like to know more about why the original solution is not working. I need a solution that doesn't require Environment, because it's working only from iOS 15+.

Comment: In order to support iOS 14 with the Environment solution you need to use:
`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`
`presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

Comment: Indeed, I'm correcting my answer for iOS 14.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @La pieuvre answer, to make this handling even easier on iOS 14 (like the handling for iOS 15 +). We can create an extension for **EnvironmentValues**

```
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dismiss: () -> Void {
        { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }
    }
}
```

Then we can use it in a more cleaner way, like in iOS 15+

```
struct ScreenC: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Screen C")
            Button("Back to Screen B") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So we can get rid of calling `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` all the time